# open .ply mesh files with matlab (or convert to readable format in python)

Tags: python, matlab, mesh

I'm using the [MPI FAUST](http://faust.is.tue.mpg.de) dataset - containing `.ply` mesh files.
The .ply headers is as follows:

```
ply
format binary_little_endian 1.0
element vertex 6890
property float x
property float y
property float z
element face 13776
property list uchar int vertex_indices
end_header
```

And I was able to load them using the `pymesh` library:

```
a =  pymesh.load_mesh("tr_scan_019.ply")
a.vertices
array([[ 0.00294954,  0.3746013 , -0.18593594],
       [-0.01065227,  0.30154902,  0.03721469],
       [ 0.01176361,  0.37961864, -0.18658873],
       ...,
       [ 0.39272201,  1.0824883 ,  0.0319973 ],
       [-0.29185328,  1.00391781,  0.03810745],
       [ 0.39623857,  1.08823442,  0.03612268]])
>>> a.faces
array([[ 49533,  45416,  52207],
       [141371,  38353,  56906],
       [ 57747,  59888,  43636],
       ...,
       [132845, 180118, 175435],
       [166162, 173001, 166963],
       [177654, 173001, 166162]], dtype=int32)
```

I need to load them to a readable matlab mesh format, as I have mesh processing functions I wrote in matlab.

I tried using matlab functions to load them, but all are from 2015, and didn't work (e.g [gptoolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/49692-gptoolbox?focused=d010394c-cebb-7b3e-c4a2-d962702342a0&tab=function) read only the vertexes).

Is there a way to write the mesh to a readable matlab format so I could later read it properly in matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [meshio](https://github.com/nschloe/meshio) (a project of mine) to convert your ply file to a range of other formats, perhaps one of them is natively readable in MATLAB. Just

```
pip3 install meshio --user
```

and then

```
meshio-convert in.ply out.vtk
```

on the command line.

If that doesn't work, you could just dump the data into something simple like csv from within Python,

```py
import meshio

mesh = meshio.read("in.ply")
# mesh.points, mesh.cells, ...
```